# ExecuteScalar if DBNull issue

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, winforms

I was trying to handle DbNull exception like this:

```
string sql_com_sumcastka = "SELECT SUM(price) AS sumprice FROM kliplat WHERE akce='" + zakce.Text + "' AND year=" + year;
            SqlCommand sc2 = new SqlCommand(sql_com_sumprice, spojeni);
            spojeni.Open();

            if (sc2 != DBNull.Value)
            {
                int result = Convert.ToInt32(sc2.ExecuteScalar());
            }
            else
            {
                int result = 0;
            }
            spojeni.Close();

            string sql_com_update_sum = "UPDATE zajezd SET s_prijmy=@s_prijmy WHERE akce='"+zakce.Text+"' AND year="+year;
            SqlCommand sc3 = new SqlCommand(sql_com_update_sum,spojeni);

            sc3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@s_prijmy", result );
            spojeni.Open();
            sc3.ExecuteNonQuery();
            spojeni.Close();
```

But as I don't know how to properly handle if result is DBNull I get this erros: `Operator '"=' cannot be applied to operands of type system.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand and System.Dbnull`

and

> The name 'result' does not exist in the current context

My problem is this line of code:

```
if (sc2 != DBNull.Value)
        {
            int result = Convert.ToInt32(sc2.ExecuteScalar());
        }
        else
        {
            int result = 0;
        }
```

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Why would `sc2` be `DBNull.Value`? You have just assigned it to a new `SqlCommand`. You should be checking whether `sc2.ExecuteScalar` is `DBNull.Value`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ExecuteScalar doesn't return DBNull (unless..., please read comments below) but null and you need to test the return value of ExecuteScalar not the SqlCommand that executes the command

```
   int sumOfPrice = 0;
   object result = sc2.ExecuteScalar();
   if(result != null)
       sumOfPrice = Convert.ToInt32(result);
```

[From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx)

> ExecuteScalar returns the first column of the first row in the result
> set, or a null reference (Nothing in Visual Basic) if the result set
> is empty.

As a side note, do not use string concatenation to build a command text to pass to your database. You risk Sql Injection and parsing erroros. Use instead a parameterized query like this

```
string sql_com_sumcastka = "SELECT SUM(price) AS sumprice FROM kliplat " + 
                           "WHERE akce=@zak AND year=@year";
SqlCommand sc2 = new SqlCommand(sql_com_sumprice, spojeni);
sc2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@zak", zakce.Text);
sc2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@year", year);
```

Comment: ExecuteScalar could return `DBNull.Value` if the result of the query returns null, however his query could never return `DBNull.Value`

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Could you elaborate with an example? Your affirmation seems to contradict the docs

Comment: "*ExecuteScalar returns the first column of the first row in the result set*" If the first column of the first row in the result set was the value `NULL` in SQL ExecuteScalar will return `DBNull.Value` if no rows where returned ExecuteScalar will return `null`. Also I take back my statement, SUM can retun `NULL` [if there are no rows in the result set](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e2487/1)

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I see, point taken then. I understand, A little unusual but possible in some situation

Answer (score 6):

Here is the correct way to do that

```
var objResult = sc2.ExecuteScalar();

if (objResult != DBNull.Value && objResult != null )
{
    int result = (int)objResult; //you can just do a normal cast, "SUM(X)" returns a int.
}
else
{
    int result = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A `SqlCommand` can never be compared to `DBNull.Value` in your example. What it sounds like you want is to check the result of your execute scalar invocation to see if that is null:

```
var result = sc2.ExecuteScalar();

if(result as DBNull == null)
{
    // value is not null, do processing
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know the answer is late but this is the simplest answer that I have found

```
SELECT (SUM(price),0) FROM kliplat
```

If the result is `null` it will be replaced with `0`